# How to fallback to empty array without breaking the implicit type for the "map" operation?

Tags: typescript

I have a Promise returning objects and I want to fallback to empty array if it fails.
[See the type error in the Playground.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.9.2#code/BQQwzgngdgxgBMAlHAvAPjgbwFBz-mAeyjABc4BzAU1IGVoYAhEGAawFcAHMVOcBhMnRwA2phAAuOAEYANHABGUgEwBfALoBuXPjwB6PXAAWhAO5xShOADMQAGzsKWrC1aoBbTqQh8ATr5AfUwBLUhN2cgVfKhBWYKgKCyMqCwhOKgB%20HV0iEnJIWGY2Lh4UPlMQUMoaekLnEqQAOhgQUhgjYCRUDBF1RG1dfUNg6zgASTgwdJgRn290uCoAD047YJnSOwh5KpCHOFNCX1YpbPwDOFyySYYijm4pcSkodncFKl95JTgXt4-VXq8EAVKrUOi3ercJotNodLrCXr9M54ApMSFgRruECcYBOYqcbqXYhgQh2KiNOyECi4yGIJGqRBITRAA)

```js
(async () => {
      const getSyncBackups = async () => [{a: 1, b: 2}];
      // how to fallback to empty array without breaking the type in the `.map` operation?
      const syncBackups = await getSyncBackups().catch(() => []);
      // if I specify type explicitly, it will work: 
      // const syncBackups: {a: number, b: number}[] = await getSyncBackups().catch(() => []);
      syncBackups.map(backup => console.log(backup));  // TS2349: This expression is not callable. Each member of the union type '(<U>(callbackfn: (value: { a: number; b: number; }, index: number, array: { a: number; b: number; }[]) => U, thisArg?: any) => U[]) | (<U>(callbackfn: (value: never, index: number, array: never[]) => U, thisArg?: any) => U[])' has signatures, but none of those signatures are compatible with each other.
})();
```

I know I can fix it by explicitly specifying type of my `syncBackups`, but it feels redundant.
TypeScript should know that calling `map` on something with type `{a: number, b: number}[] | []` can only have items of type `{a: number, b: number}`. Right?

Can I report this as a feature request or am I missing something obvious?

Thanks!

Comment: TypeScript doesn't know what `catch` returns, and there is no guarantee it will return the same type as `getSyncBackups`. Type the array returned by `catch` and everything will work.

Comment: Typing something should never be redundant, espescially in these cases

Comment: @HereticMonkey What if I use `catch(() => [] as const);`. Then TypeScript knows it returns readonly empty array. That really should be enough to deduce the implicit type and fix the error.